# Safety concerns regarding Binary Search

Tags: arrays, c, binary-search

The binary search algorithm is pretty cool. Here's the basic, recursive implementation in C that I see everywhere on the internet:

```
int binsearch(int arr[], int l, int h, int key) {

    if (l < h) {

        int mid = (l + h) / 2;

        if (key == arr[mid])
            return mid;
        else
        if (key < arr[mid])
            return binsearch(arr, l, mid - 1, key);
        else
            return binsearch(arr, mid + 1, h, key);

    } else {

        return -1; /* if key isn't found, -1 is a sign of failure */

    }
}

/* calling and printing in main */

printf("%d\n", binsearch(array, 0, n - 1, my_key));
```

Although there may seem nothing wrong with this, when I run this, it doesn't work for marginal elements of the array (i.e. `arr[0]` and `arr[n-1]`), returning `-1`. Here's what worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int A[] = { -6, -5, -3, -1, 0, 4, 5, 9, 12, 13 }; /* don't count, n = 10 */
int k;

int binsearch(int s, int e, int n) {

    if (s < e) {

        int mid = (s + e) / 2;
        
        if (n == A[mid]) {

            return mid;

        } else
        if (n < A[mid]) {

            return binsearch(s, mid, n); /* change: mid-1 */

        } else {

            return binsearch(mid, e, n); /* change: mid+1 */

        }

    } else {

        return -1;

    }
}

int main() {

     printf("key: ");
     scanf("%d", &k);

     printf("Place in array: %d\n", binsearch(0, 10, k)); /* change: n-1 to n */
}
```

My question: are these changes unsafe to memory (for example, is the function accessing memory out of array, as it should be 9, not 10) or inefficient? Is there something I'm missing that wouldn't have required these changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Here's the basic, recursive implementation in C that I see everywhere on the internet"* A couple of links supporting that would be good.

Comment: Passing the wrong arguments to a function is always dangerous. Naming all parameters as some 1 letter nonsense is always dangerous. Using recursion is always dangerous. Using recursion is often very inefficient. Solution: ensure that the arguments are correct. Write self-documenting code with meaningful variable names. Switch out the recursive algorithm for a loop. Also avoid global variables.

Comment: Personally, I prefer a dichotomic implementation where you only use one <= comparison inside the loop to narrow the search interval to two successive elements rather than performing early termination in case of equality. This version is faster on average (and always faster in case of a key not found).

Comment: OT: `don't count` instead of `const size_t n = sizeof A/sizeof A[0];`... I'd have more confidence if the compiler counted the number of elements... If you're concerned about "safety" then use the tools to maximum advantage instead of putting things in comments...

Comment: xcell, A 2nd comment to emphasize [@Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781180/safety-concerns-regarding-binary-search#comment131978087_74781180) good point about not using recursion, when simply alternatives exist.  Perhaps recursion here is OK for learning purposes, yet it is uses like this that give recursion a bad name.  Use recursion where _needed_, not where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another corner problem in both of OP's functions.

**Overflow**

`int mid = (l+h)/2;` risks overflow in `l+h`.

Given `-1 <= l <= h`, a non-overflow solution is

```
int mid = l + (h-l)/2;
```

This also works when `l, h` are some *unsigned* type.

**Type**

Array indexes may exceed the `int` range.  Use `size_t` to handle even the largest of arrays.

Recall `size_t` is an *unsigned* type and so the algorithm needs to guard against `mid-1` when `mid == 0`.  The classic approach if not not specify the last index, but the last index + 1 and adjust calculations and tests accordingly.

---

**Alterative**

Some untested code incorporating the above to give OP an idea.

```
/*
 * Return a pointer to the matching array element or NULL when not found. 
 * nmemb is the number of elements in the array.  May be 0 to SIZE_MAX.
 */
int *binsearch_int(int key, const int *base, size_t nmemb) {
  while (nmemb > 0) {
    size_t mid = nmemb/2;
    if(key == base[mid]) {
      return &base[mid];
    }

    if(key < base[mid]) {
      nmemb = mid;
    } else {
      base += mid + 1;
      nmemb -= mid + 1;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code copied from the net (i.e. the first code block) is obviously wrong. It can never work for an array with size 1. I think there is a simple typo. Try this change:

```
if(l < h){   --->  if(l <= h){
```

I think it will fix the first code block.

Your rewrite of the code doesn't work either. Try running it on this array:

```
 int A[] = {-6};
```

and do the search like:

```
printf("Place in array: %d\n", binsearch(0, 1, 10));
```

Now you have an endless loop...

Answer (score 1):

You changed the semantics of `e` from *index of last element* to *index to one past the end*. Per se this is safe, even a pointer to one past the end of any array is a valid pointer, though you must not dereference it, this would yield undefined behaviour. C++, by the way, *lives* from this priciple, any standard algorithm operates on two pointers to the beginning and one past the end respectively (well, actually iterators, an extended concept, but pointers are such ones, too).

There's an issue in your variant, though: The change from `mid + 1` to `mid` for the second recursive call was wrong. The semantics of `s` as begin of the search range hasn't changed. The value at `mid` already *has* been tested, so you don't need to include it as start value for the remaining array either. Even worse: If `s` and `e` differ only by 1 then `mid` will be equal to `s`, and if you are looking for a value smaller then you will recurse with the same values for `s` and `e`, ending up in endless recursion!

In contrast the original variant had an error in as well:

As `l` and `h` mark both a point *within* the array the case of `l == h` denotes an array of length 1. The `mid` value in this case still needs to be checked, so the condition in the original variant actually needs to be

```
if(l <= h)
//    ^ (!)
```

to be able to find the end value, too.